# Trying to read from two databases to check if an account exists

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to create a login system that will load a different homepage based upon what database their information is stored in - Whether they're a customer or a business.

I have created my registration and it is okay when I am trying to check just one database and it will log them in successfully.

I am unsure where to put this bit of code for the second database though - I keep receiving errors whenever i place it somewhere, I have used a similar sort of code for the first database.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "s", $ema);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
                $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt2);
```

This is the code in full.

```
} elseif (!empty($ema) AND !empty($pas)) {
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE email1=?;";
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users2 WHERE email2=?;";
            $stmt1 = mysqli_stmt_init ($conn);
            $stmt2 = mysqli_stmt_init ($conn1);
            //Check if there was an error reading data from database
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt1, $sql1) AND !mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt2, $sql2)) {
                header("Location: ../splash.php?error=sqlerror");
} else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "s", $ema);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
                $result1 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt1);

                if($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                    $pwdcheck1 = password_verify($pas, $row1['pwd1']);

                    if($pwdcheck1 == false) {
                        header("Location:../splash.php?error=wrongdetails");
                        exit();
                    //If a username and password in the business account correlate, then load the business index.
                    } elseif ($pwdcheck1 == true){
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['userlog1'] = $row1['idUsers1'];
                        header("Location: ../../b/index1.php?login=success");
                        exit();
                    }

                } elseif ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                    $pwdcheck2 = password_verify($pas, $row2['pwd2']);

                    if($pwdcheck2 == false) {
                        header("Location: ../splash.php?error=wrongdetails");
                        exit();
                    } elseif ($pwdcheck2 == true) {
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['userlog2'] = $row2['idUsers2'];
                        header("Location: ../../t/index2.php?login=success");
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            header("Location: ../splash.php?error=usernotfound");
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have two users tables in the first place? there should be just **one** table

Comment: You need to have only a single table for the logins, and perhaps a column in that table stating which type of login it should be

Answer (score 1):

The fact you should have a single users table aside, the problem is coming from the numerous conditions, every one of them being useless.

Basically if you need to get the results from two queries,  then you should execute them right away, one by one. *Without any intermediate conditions*

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE email1=?;";
        mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $ema);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)

        if (!$row) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users2 WHERE email2=?;";
            mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $ema);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        }
```

Now you can check the password

```
if(($row && password_verify($pas, $row['pwd'])) {
    // OK
} else {
    // not OK
}
```

Comment: I have since altered all my stuff into one database - I'm a moron who overcomplicates things.

Thanks though